# Making image clickable in gridview imagefield

Tags: asp.net

I have an image field in a gridview as this:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PictureID" 
       DataImageUrlFormatString="~/UploadedImages/{0}.jpg" HeaderText="Image" 
       ReadOnly="True">
    <ControlStyle Width="100px"  />
</asp:ImageField>
```

I want when user click on any of the images, it should take them to another page `UploadedImage.aspx`, displaying the clicked image in full size.

Can someone help me accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use TemplateColumn where you put an ImageButton control in that template and then handle the RowCommand event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion on the topic, with a few ideas on solutions, such as

- Handle the onClick-event of the image
- Inline Javascript
- Plain old a href

http://forums.asp.net/t/1303912.aspx